# find overlapping dates within mongoDB array objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I have a MongoDB document collection with multiple arrays that looks like this :

```
{
"_id": "1235847",
  "LineItems": [
    {
      "StartDate": ISODate("2017-07-31T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
      "EndDate": ISODate("2017-09-19T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
      "Amount": {"$numberDecimal": "0.00"}
    },
    {
      "StartDate": ISODate("2022-03-20T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
      "EndDate": ISODate("2022-10-21T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
      "Amount": {"$numberDecimal": "6.38"}
    },
    {
      "StartDate": ISODate("2022-09-20T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
      "EndDate": ISODate("9999-12-31T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
      "Amount": {"$numberDecimal": "6.17"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a simple way to find documents where the startdate has overlapped with previously startdate, enddate?
The startdate can not be before previous end dates within the array
The start/end can not be between previous start/end dates within the array

The below works but I don't want to hardcode the array index to find all the documents

```
{
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $gt: [
                'LineItems.3.EndDate',
                'LineItems.2.StartDate'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the `"LineItems"` array you show is improperly formed - too many `}`.  Would you edit your question to accurately show the documents?

Comment: updated the above so document is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could find docs where `"StartDate"` is earlier than the immediately previous `"EndDate"`.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$getField": {
      "field": "overlapped",
      "input": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {"$slice": ["$LineItems", 1, {"$size": "$LineItems"}]},
          "initialValue": {
            "overlapped": false,
            "prevEnd": {"$first": "$LineItems.EndDate"}
          },
          "in": {
            "overlapped": {
              "$or": [
                "$$value.overlapped",
                {"$lt": ["$$this.StartDate", "$$value.prevEnd"]}
              ]
            },
            "prevEnd": "$$this.EndDate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lKgSHnf78L2).

Comment: Fantastic. That has worked!!! I wish I had your knowledge of mongo aggs @rickhg12hs

Comment: @charlieraly  You're welcome.  Just answer `mongodb` tagged questions here for a couple of months and you'll expand your knowledge tremendously.